# SQL + use aggregate function results in the same query

Tags: sql, hive

Im working on hive, i need to aggregate some values and using those aggregated results need to derive another value.
For example:
Sales

```
Item .  sold_cnt . sold_price
-----------------------------
1         3         9
1         4         12
2         4         20
1         2          6
```

No i want to write a query that would aggregate sold_cnt and sold_price per item and also determine the individual item cost.

As of now am doing this but dont think thats right. Can some one help?

```
SELECT ITEM, TOTALCNT, TOTALPRICE, (TOTALPRICE/TOTALCNT) AS INDIPRICE 
FROM(
   SELECT ITEM, SUM(SOLD_CNT) AS TOTALCNT, SUM(SOLD_PRICE) AS TOTALPRICE, 
   FROM SALES GROUP BY ITEM
) A GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need a subquery. Try this

```
SELECT ITEM, 
      SUM(SOLD_CNT) AS TOTALCNT, 
      SUM(SOLD_PRICE) AS TOTALPRICE, 
      SUM(SOLD_PRICE)/SUM(SOLD_CNT) AS Weighted_average_item_cost
FROM SALES 
GROUP BY ITEM
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you still want to use your method of query, you can do it without a `GROUP BY` in the outer query.

```
SELECT A.ITEM, A.TOTALCNT, A.TOTALPRICE, (A.TOTALPRICE/A.TOTALCNT) AS INDIPRICE 
FROM
(
  SELECT ITEM, SUM(SOLD_CNT) AS TOTALCNT, SUM(SOLD_PRICE) AS TOTALPRICE 
  FROM SALES 
  GROUP BY ITEM
) A
```